# How to find elements of a ring $\mathbb{Z}_n$ in Mathematica

Tags: ring-theory, mathematica

How to find elements of a commutative ring with unity $\mathbb{Z}_n$, (under addition and multiplication modulo $n$) by using Mathimatica, which satisfying the following condition.
Let $x, y \in R = \mathbb{Z}_n$ be two nonzero elements such that $xy = x$, here $y \neq 1$. Please guide me how to find all such $y \in \mathbb{Z}_n$. Manually I can do this but it take too much time for big rings like $\mathbb{Z}_{60}$ thats why I need to find these elements by using mathematica. hope you understand.

Comment: In general, you want to factorize $n=ab$ and take integers $0<j<n/a, 0<k<n/b$. Then let $x=ja, y= kb+1$. Then $x(y-1)=(jk)(ab)=0$. Alternatively, you can use Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: At heart, you need to realize you are solving $x(y-1)=0$.

Comment: Try http://mathematica.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Do you want to find all such $y$, or all such $x,y$? All such $y$ is just any $y$ such that $y-1$ has a common factor with $n$. There are $n-\phi(n)$ such $y$, or $n-1-\phi(n)$ if you are excluding $y-1=0$.

Comment: thank you so much Thomas you guide me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to list just the values $y$, then you can find the prime factors of $n$ and the find any $y$ such that $y-1$ is divisible by one of those prime factors.

For $n=60$, the primes are $2,3,5$. You can list the even numbers first:

$$y-1=2,4,6,\dots 58 \text{ or }\\
 3,9,15, 21, \dots, 57\text{ or }\\
5,25,35,55
$$

if you want to list all solutions $(x,y)$:

I'm not sure about Mathematica, but this approach might work better than trial and error. It enumerates all pairs $x.y$ that solve the equation.

For each integer $x$, compute $\gcd(x,n)$. Then we have that $y-1$ can be any multiple of $\frac{n}{\gcd(x,n)}$. Give that you want $y-1\neq 0$, this gives ${\gcd(x,n)}-1$ values of $y$ for any $x$.

So the pseudo-code would look something like:

```
for x in (0..(n-1)) {
    g=gcd(x,n)
    y1=n/g
    for k in (1..(g-1)) {
        y = k*y1+1
        ... emit pair (x,y) ...
    }
}
```

You might want to exclude the case $x=0$, as well, of course, but you didn't state that.